$C^n(X)$ separability
Using Stone-Weiestrass thm we can say easily that $(C^n(K), \| . \|_{\infty})$ where $K \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ compact,  is separable as subspace of separable metric space.
Anyway i'm interested to the separability of $(C^n(K), \| . \|_{C^n})$, where $\| f \|_{C^n} = \sum_{|\alpha| \leq n} \| D^{\alpha}f\|_{\infty} $. In this second case the topology is more fine then in supnorm's case, so i don't think we can exploit the separability of the first case.
Moreover on wiki in 'Example' section, i read that $(C^n([a, b]), \| . \|_{C^n})$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n \oplus C([a, b])$ using Taylor thm, how can prove it? Maybe is useful to prove easily the separability?

Are you assuming that $K$ is compact? In general, your functions are not bounded.

Yes, absolutely, it's a typo. Thanks

For the main result, note that $\iota: C^n(K) \to \oplus_{|\alpha| \leq n} C(K)$, $\iota(f) = (D^\alpha f)_\alpha$ is an embedding (isometric if the direct sum is the $\ell^1$-direct sum). The space on the RHS is a direct sum of finitely many separable spaces, so it is separable itself. Thus, $C^n(K)$ is a subspace of a separable space, whence it is separable.
For the case of $[a, b]$, the claimed isomorphism $F: C^n([a, b]) \to \mathbb{R}^n \oplus C([a, b])$ is given by $F(f) = (f(a), f’(a), \cdots, f^{(n-1)}(a)) \oplus f^{(n)}$. Since $\mathbb{R}^n \oplus C([a, b])$ is separable (being a direct sum of two separable spaces), so is $C^n([a, b])$.
